# Result of unit test always "Received:0"

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, jsx, enzyme

Unit test code cannot read component "jsx" content
the test result is always "Received: 0"

This is a screenshot of the unit test result using enzyme and jest with react.js

[image]

//**************************************component.js*************************************************//

```
class NetworkConfig extends Component {
constructor() {
super();
  this.state = {
    dataDeviceConfig: {
    dhcp: false,
    macAddress: '',
    ipAddress: '',
    subMask: '',
    dns: '',
    gateway: '',
    },
    alertMessage: "",
    loader: false
 };
  }
          render() {
          return (
       <div>
       {console.log("Diagnostic Data", this.state.dataDeviceConfig)}
       <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
       <div className="sn-forms-settings">

         <FormItem
          label={<IntlMessages id="settings.label.DHCP" />}
         >
          {getFieldDecorator('dhcp', {
          })(
            <Switch ............... />
          )}
        </FormItem>

        <FormItem
          label={(
            <span>
              <IntlMessages id="settings.label.MacAdres" />&nbsp;
            </span>
          )}
         >
          {getFieldDecorator('macAddress', {
            initialValue: this.state.dataDeviceConfig.macAddress
          })(
            <label name="macAddress">{this.state.dataDeviceConfig.macAddress}</label>
          )}
        </FormItem>
      </div>
    </Form>

  </div>

  );
  }
  }

 const mapStateToProps = ({ settingSense, common }) => {
 const { dataDeviceConfig } = settingSense;

 const {
   loader,
   alertMessage,
   showAlert,
   alertMessageStatus,
   alertMessageComponent
 } = common;

 return {
 dataDeviceConfig,
 loader,
 alertMessage,
 showAlert,
 alertMessageStatus,
 alertMessageComponent
 }
 };
 const NetworkConfigForm = Form.create()(NetworkConfig);
 export default injectIntl(connect(mapStateToProps, {
 getDevicEtherConfigAction, setDevicEtherConfigAction
 , showLoaderAction, hideAlertAction, hideLoaderAction
 })(NetworkConfigForm));
```

//**************************************component.test.js**********************************************//

```
 import React from 'react';
 import Enzyme,{shallow,configur } from 'enzyme';
 import EnzymeAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
 import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
 import NetworkConfigForm  from '../../../.....................';
 import {Input} from "antd";
 import {mountWithIntl,shallowWithIntl} from '../../helpers/intl-enzyme-test-helper.js';

 Enzyme.configure({
 adapter: new EnzymeAdapter(),
 disableLifecycleMethods: false
 });


 describe('Network Config Test', () => {
 it('render NetworkConfig Component', () => {
 const state = {
    settingSense:{
        dataDeviceConfig: {
            dhcp: false,
            macAddress: '',
            ipAddress: '',
            subMask: '',
            dns: '',
            gateway: '',
        }
    },
    common:{
            loader: false,
            alertMessage:'',
            showAlert: false,
            alertMessageStatus:'MESSAGE_SUCCESS',
            alertMessageComponent:'ALERT_DEVICE_ETHER_CONFIG' 
    }
    };
    const mockStore = configureMockStore();
    const store = mockStore(state);
    const wrapper = shallowWithIntl(<NetworkConfigForm  store={store}/>).dive();
    expect(wrapper.find('.sn-forms-settings').children().length).toEqual(2)   

   });
   });
```

Comment: try wrapper.dive().children().find(".sn-form.settings")..... if you get this element then try searching children

Comment: Thanks , I tried this line of code but the same result I got.
The problem of reading the jsx content of the component still exists.